Queries on oauth2.0 flows
I’ve looked into various sources to understand OAuth 2.0 flows, but I’d like clarification on a couple of points:

The resource owner is responsible for granting the client access to resources. How does the resource owner (or authorization server) verify that the request is coming from an authentic client? While the authorization server typically authenticates the resource owner to ensure the right entity is requesting access, how does it ensure that authorization is given to the correct client? I’d like to explore this question within the context of the authorization code flow. Is this a relevant inquiry within the scope of OAuth 2.0?

In many systems, multiple users can log in and access the same resource (read/modify). In such cases, how are the concepts of resource and resource owner defined? Can a resource be owned by multiple owners?


I try to understand oauth2.0 flow from training and oauth2.0 specification and other videos.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
